# Basic recursive descent parser in C

Tags: c, strings, parsing, portability, duplicate-code

The purpose of this code is to evaluate simple integer expressions that make use of the C arithmetic and bitwise operators while respecting C operator precedence and parenthesis. I wrote this code with portability in mind, making no use of implementation defined, or undefined constructs to my knowledge. However there are a lot of duplicate patterns here, and if someone could provide some insight as to how to rewrite the code more compactly, and confirm that my code is in fact portable standard C, that would be great.

The code works by dividing the expression into groups separated by the lowest precedence operator, and then dividing those groups into groups separated by the second lowest precedence operator, and so on.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
static jmp_buf jmp;
static unsigned long p6(const char **);
static unsigned long p0(const char **const str) {
    if (isdigit(**str)) return strtoul(*str, (char **)str, 0);
    else switch (*(*str)++) {
        case '+':
            return +p0(str);
        case '-':
            return -p0(str);
        case '~':
            return ~p0(str);
        case '(': {
            const unsigned long r = p6(str);
            if (*(*str)++ == ')') return r;
        }
    }
    longjmp(jmp, errno = EINVAL);
}
static unsigned long p1(const char **const str) {
    unsigned long r = p0(str);
    for (;;) {
        switch (**str) {
            case '*':
                ++*str;
                r *= p0(str);
                continue;
            case '/':
                ++*str;
                r /= p0(str);
                continue;
            case '%':
                ++*str;
                r %= p0(str);
                continue;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
static unsigned long p2(const char **const str) {
    unsigned long r = p1(str);
    for (;;) {
        switch (**str) {
            case '+':
                ++*str;
                r += p1(str);
                continue;
            case '-':
                ++*str;
                r -= p1(str);
                continue;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
static unsigned long p3(const char **const str) {
    unsigned long r = p2(str);
    for (;;) {
        switch (**str) {
            case '<':
                ++*str;
                r <<= p2(str);
                continue;
            case '>':
                ++*str;
                r >>= p2(str);
                continue;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
static unsigned long p4(const char **const str) {
    unsigned long r = p3(str);
    for (; **str == '&'; r &= p3(str)) ++*str;
    return r;
}
static unsigned long p5(const char **const str) {
    unsigned long r = p4(str);
    for (; **str == '^'; r ^= p4(str)) ++*str;
    return r;
}
static unsigned long p6(const char **const str) {
    unsigned long r = p5(str);
    for (; **str == '|'; r |= p5(str)) ++*str;
    return r;
}
unsigned long parse(const char **const str) {
    return setjmp(jmp) ? 0 : p6(str);
}
#include <stdio.h>
int main(const int argc, const char **argv) {
    while (*++argv) {
        const unsigned long r = parse(&(const char *){*argv});
        if (errno) {
            perror(*argv);
            errno = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if (printf("%lu\n", r) < 0)
            return errno;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Portable?**

"I wrote this code with portability in mind," --> Standard C lacks `EINVAL`.

```
longjmp(jmp, errno = EINVAL);
```

**Negative `char`**

`isdigit(**str)` is UB when `**str < 0` and not `EOF`.  Best to only pass `unsigned char` values to `is...()`.

**Pedantic: Code assumes `argc > 0`**

If `argc == 0`, `++argv` is a  problem.

(Recall *portability*) Rather than seek the *null pointer* at the end of the `argv[]` list, consider indexing.

```
// int main(const int argc, const char **argv) {
//   while (*++argv) {
//     const unsigned long r = parse(&(const char *){*argv});
int main(const int argc, const char **argv) {
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    const unsigned long r = parse(&(const char *){argv[i]});
```

**No white-space**

I'd expect such parsers to be white-space friendly and not stop due to some `' '`.  I see how this may over complicate code for this initial effort.

**`<`, `>` for shifting?**

Consider `<<` for shift and `<` for compare.

**Vertical spacing**

Some vertical space would improve code readability.

**Non-standard `main()` signature**

Drop the `const`.

Some compilers may whine.  Note: "The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program," C17dr § 5.1.2.2.1 2.

```
// int main(const int argc, const char **argv) {
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

**Minor: Unneeded `else`**

```
// if (isdigit(**str)) return strtoul(*str, (char **)str, 0);
// else switch (*(*str)++) {
if (isdigit(**str)) return strtoul(*str, (char **)str, 0);
switch (*(*str)++) {
```

**right-to-left Bug?**

Evaluation of unary plus/minus and logical bitwise complement looks left-to-right.  I'd expect right-to-left.

**Subtle good code**

Code uses `parse(&(const char *){*argv})` rather than `parse(argv)`.   `parse(argv)` may modify `*argv` and that is potential UB.

**Minor: `errno = 0`**

Best set just before the `parse()` call.

With code as is, makes no difference, yet from a template POV, better to see example code setting `errno = 0` explicitly.

```
    errno = 0; // Add
    const unsigned long r = parse(&(const char *){*argv});
```

**`printf()` and `errno`**

Unclear why code returns `errno`.  `printf()` is not specified to set `errno` under any condition.

Consider:

```
if (printf("%lu\n", r) < 0)
  // return errno;
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Comment: `argc` is never 0. `argv[0]` is the program name... right?

Comment: @user16217248 "`argc` is never 0" --> _never_ is along time.   [Handle `argc` equal to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28019827/2410359).  Better to code to spec, than only experience.

Comment: But... why? Is there any rational for this seemingly pointless allowance of `argc == 0`? Is it really hard to require that implementations with no concept of program name pass a pointer to a null byte for `argv[0]` and make `argc >= 1`?

Comment: Also, since parameters are local to the function they were declared, declaring `argc` as `const` is invisible to any implementation.

Comment: I quoted some of your observations in the review of the latest question.

Comment: @user16217248 "make `argc >= 1`" --> C could have done that.  It didn't.  Better to code to spec rather than what we think it should have been.  1) `argc == 0` is common in embedded applications. 2) `main()` can be recursively called with all sorts of combinations 3) `execv()` calls allow for `argc== 0`.  Consider a `if (argc > 0)` test simply defensive programming.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Would `while (*argv) { *argv++; }` instead of `while (*++argv) { *argv; }` solve the problem?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Tested it, but does not work as well as the indexing you suggested.