# C-style double expression parser

Tags: c, parsing

The purpose of this code is to parse any expression as could appear in C that involves doubles or functions that involve only doubles.

I have written parsers before:

- [Command line calculator in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283641/264812)
- [Basic recursive descent parser in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283598/264812)

This is an upgraded version that uses more descriptive variable names and structures instead of parallel arrays. This version can also handle functions of varying [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity). I was even planning on doing short string optimization here but had to skip that [because reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77299642/16217248).

```
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Symbol {
    unsigned arity, len;
    const char *name;
    union {
        double
            func0,
            (*func1)(double),
            (*func2)(double, double),
            (*func3)(double, double, double);
    };
} Symbol;
static int compar(const void *const restrict strp, const void *const restrict p) {
    const unsigned len = ((const Symbol *)p)->len;
    const char
        *const str = *(const char *const *)strp,
        *const name = ((const Symbol *)p)->name;
    const int cmp = memcmp(str, name, len);
    return cmp
        ? cmp
        : isalnum((unsigned char)str[len]) || str[len] == '_'
            ? str[len]-name[len]
            : (*(const char **)strp += len, 0);
}
#define SYMBOL(a, n)\
{\
    .arity = a,\
    .len = sizeof(#n)-1,\
    .name = #n,\
    .func##a = n\
}
static const Symbol symbols[] = {
    SYMBOL(0, M_1_PI),
    SYMBOL(0, M_2_PI),
    SYMBOL(0, M_2_SQRTPI),
    SYMBOL(0, M_E),
    SYMBOL(0, M_LN10),
    SYMBOL(0, M_LN2),
    SYMBOL(0, M_LOG10E),
    SYMBOL(0, M_LOG2E),
    SYMBOL(0, M_PI),
    SYMBOL(0, M_PI_2),
    SYMBOL(0, M_PI_4),
    SYMBOL(0, M_SQRT1_2),
    SYMBOL(0, M_SQRT2),
    SYMBOL(1, acos),
    SYMBOL(1, acosh),
    SYMBOL(1, asin),
    SYMBOL(1, asinh),
    SYMBOL(1, atan),
    SYMBOL(2, atan2),
    SYMBOL(1, atanh),
    SYMBOL(1, cbrt),
    SYMBOL(1, ceil),
    SYMBOL(1, cos),
    SYMBOL(1, cosh),
    SYMBOL(2, copysign),
    SYMBOL(1, erf),
    SYMBOL(1, erfc),
    SYMBOL(1, exp),
    SYMBOL(1, exp2),
    SYMBOL(1, expm1),
    SYMBOL(1, fabs),
    SYMBOL(2, fdim),
    SYMBOL(1, floor),
    SYMBOL(3, fma),
    SYMBOL(2, fmax),
    SYMBOL(2, fmin),
    SYMBOL(2, fmod),
    SYMBOL(2, hypot),
    SYMBOL(1, lgamma),
    SYMBOL(1, log),
    SYMBOL(1, log10),
    SYMBOL(1, log1p),
    SYMBOL(1, log2),
    SYMBOL(1, logb),
    SYMBOL(2, nextafter),
    SYMBOL(2, pow),
    SYMBOL(2, remainder),
    SYMBOL(1, round),
    SYMBOL(1, sin),
    SYMBOL(1, sinh),
    SYMBOL(1, sqrt),
    SYMBOL(1, tan),
    SYMBOL(1, tanh),
    SYMBOL(1, tgamma),
    SYMBOL(1, trunc)
};
static double term(const char **);
static double expr(const char **const str, const unsigned level) {
    *str += level != 0;
    for (double val = term(str);;) {
        while (isspace((unsigned char)**str))
            ++*str;
        switch (**str) {
            case '*':
                if (level > 2)
                    break;
                val *= expr(str, 2);
                continue;
            case '/':
                if (level > 2)
                    break;
                val /= expr(str, 2);
                continue;
            case '+':
                if (level > 1)
                    break;
                val += expr(str, 1);
                continue;
            case '-':
                if (level > 1)
                    break;
                val -= expr(str, 1);
                continue;
        }
        return val;
    }
}
static double term(const char **const str) {
    while (isspace((unsigned char)**str))
        ++*str;
    {
        char *end;
        const double val = strtod(*str, &end);
        if (*str != end) {
            *str = end;
            return val;
        }
    }
    if (isalpha((unsigned char)**str)) {
        const Symbol *const symbol = bsearch(str, symbols, sizeof(symbols)/sizeof(Symbol), sizeof(Symbol), compar);
        if (symbol) {
            if (!symbol->arity)
                return symbol->func0;
            while (isspace((unsigned char)**str))
                ++*str;
            if (*(*str)++ == '(') {
                double vals[symbol->arity];
                for (unsigned i = 0;;) {
                    vals[i] = expr(str, 0);
                    if (++i >= symbol->arity) {
                        if (*(*str)++ == ')') switch (symbol->arity) {
                            case 1:
                                return symbol->func1(vals[0]);
                            case 2:
                                return symbol->func2(vals[0], vals[1]);
                            case 3:
                                return symbol->func3(vals[0], vals[1], vals[2]);
                        }
                    } else if (*(*str)++ == ',')
                        continue;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else switch (*(*str)++) {
        case '+':
            return term(str);
        case '-':
            return -term(str);
        case '(':
        {
            const double val = expr(str, 0);
            if (*(*str)++ == ')')
                return val;
        }
    }
    return NAN;
}
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int arg = 1; arg < argc; ++arg)
        if (printf("%g\n", expr(&(const char *){argv[arg]}, 0)) < 0)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bug**

`memcmp(str, name, len);` lets `memcmp()` compare the first `len` bytes of the data pointed to by `str` and `name`, yet some of those are pointers to a *string* less than `len` in size.  What code needs is `strncmp()` (or perhaps even `strcmp()`) to not compare past the end of the string.

**Bug**

The `*(const char **)strp += len` relies on `bsearch()` to stop calling `cmp()` once a return value of 0 occurs.  Although this is common, `bsearch()`is not specified that way.  Instead the calling code should advance the pointer, not the compare function.

**Pedantic Bug**

`str[len]-name[len]` in `compar()` should be an `unsigned char` compare to well sort symbols that have a character outside the `[0...CHAR_MAX]` range.  Yet since, presently, `symbols[]` only employs ASCII characters, it does not make a difference.

**Non-standard macros**

`M_PI` and its 13 friends are not part of the C standard.  See [Using M_PI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5008376/2410359). Consider

```
#ifndef M_PI
  #define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif
```

**Lack of comments**

Functions deserve at least a little description to indicate its role.

**Consider `long double`**

Consider using the most precise/widest range floating point type available.

**Use a more precise output**

Rather than only 6 digits, use the [precision of the type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359):

```
// printf("%g\n", some_double)
printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DIG, some_double)
```

**Missing `break;`**

`case '(': { ..` deserves a `break;` at the end of the case or a comment indicating fall-through was desired.

**`double expr()` missing `return value;`**

TBD code needed to quiet "Problem description: No return, in function returning non-void".

---

Minor:

**Excessive use of `const object`**

`object` would simplify code presentation in many places where there is only a few lines of code.

Example:

```
        // const double val = expr(str, 0);
        double val = expr(str, 0);
        if (*(*str)++ == ')')
            return val;
```

**Format to presentation width**

Use an auto-formatter and present to the display width (e.g. ~82)

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
//        const Symbol *const symbol = bsearch(str, symbols, sizeof(symbols)/sizeof(Symbol), sizeof(Symbol), compar);
        const Symbol *const symbol = bsearch(str, symbols, 
            sizeof(symbols)/sizeof(Symbol), sizeof(Symbol), compar);
```

Note the `()` are not needed with `sizeof` *object*.

**Avoid names that differ only in case**

```
//    v----v        v----v
const Symbol *const symbol
```

**Vertical spacing**

Between functions, types, consider a blank line.

Comment: Oh, I tried to eliminate the excessively long lines, but looks like I missed one.

Comment: @user16217248 Tip: use an auto-formatter.  Do _not_ manually format code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by making `str[len]-name[len]` an `unsigned char`. You mean like `(unsigned char)(str[len]-name[len])`? I don't know what that solves. Also the `double expr()` misses a `return` at the end because the 'end' is not reachable. The loop runs forever until the return statement at the end of the loop body is reached.

Comment: @user16217248 When `char` is _signed_, `str[len]` is of one sign (say +50) and `name[len]` is the other sign (say -60), `str[len]-name[len]` is positive (110), yet if the strings are accessed via `unsigned char *`, `str[len]-name[len]` is like `50 - (256-60)` with a negative result.  Which is correct for searching a _sorted_ list? `strcmp()` and `memcmp()` perform as if in the 2nd case.  You code does not experience this issue as the functions all have ASCII names.  Yet if [π](https://www.ascii-code.com/character/π) was added to to the calculator, we may have an issue.

Comment: @user16217248 Enabling many warnings is a good thing and flags issues as in `expr()`.  Coding intentionally a missing return (even if that path is not possible) makes for false positives problems.  Better code does not do that.  Of course we want our code to be correct, yet it also should _look_ correct.  Consider alternatives.

Comment: Well I could replace the `return` at the end of the loop with `break` and just put the `return` at the end of the function.